# Target class [Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession] does not exist. why am i getting this error

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession] does not exist.
```

I installed jetstream on my Laravel project and got this error. Does anyone know the cause of the error?

Comment: If it's possible, try to install jetstream on a fresh laravel.

Comment: I have developed my project a lot. I Installed Jetstream and Project gave such an error. Could my project be garbage?

Comment: In your project does `AuthenticateSession.php` exist here?: `vendor\laravel\jetstream\src\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession.php`?

Comment: I did the project again. Thanks for help